# What does it mean, "eyebrows deep in every vice"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Michael denies the truth that horse racing is the only vice for Lord George.

> Michael: I've always taken vice to be the definition of any criminal
>   activity or wicked behavior involving prostitution, pornography or
>   drugs, so, no...racing is definitely not your only vice, your
>   lordship. I'd say you're **eyebrows deep in every vice** known to man.

What does it mean, "eyebrows deep in every vice"?

I find these line in *The Gentlemen 2019*

Comment: If you’re **knee-deep** in something (water, for example), the water comes up to your knees; you can also be eyebrows-deep, which would then be when the water comes all the way up to your eyebrows. I’m sure you can imagine which would be more detrimental to your health, assuming you don’t have a snorkelling mask.

Comment: please post answer.

Comment: I think you need to stop analysing and try to enjoy the film. If you need to ask this many questions to understand it, you should consider if the level is too high for your learning. Or you should try to enjoy the film without understanding every phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"You're eyebrows deep in every vice known to man" means that he engages excessively in every vice that you can think of: gambling, prostitutes, alcohol, drugs, etc.

This is similar to the expression "up to your eyebrows" which means that you are very deep into something - so deep that you are (metaphorically) buried up to your eyebrows. For example:

- "I'm up to my eyebrows in alligators!" = (humorous) I have so many tasks to accomplish that I can't keep up.
- "He's up to his eyebrows in debt" = he has way too much debt; he is very deeply in debt.